# Connecting Waveshare ov2640 camera, Raspberry Pi Pico and external SD Card for capturing images and saving to sd card.Code is throwing "pin in use"err

Tags: pi-pico

Using the below code for connecting Waveshare OV2640 camera and External SD Card to Raspberry Pi Pico. The code throwing the following error

[image]

```
import os
import board
import busio as io
import digitalio
import storage
import adafruit_sdcard
import sdcardio
import adafruit_ov2640
import microcontroller
from time import sleep
import time
from displayio import (
    Bitmap,
    Group,
    TileGrid,
    FourWire,
    release_displays,
    ColorConverter,
    Colorspace,
)
SD_CS = board.GP13

spi = io.SPI(board.GP10, board.GP11, board.GP12)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(SD_CS)
sdcard = adafruit_sdcard.SDCard(spi, cs)
vfs = storage.VfsFat(sdcard)
storage.mount(vfs, "/sd")

with digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP10) as reset:
    reset.switch_to_output(False)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    bus = busio.I2C(board.GP9, board.GP8)
    
cam = adafruit_ov2640.OV2640(
    bus,
    data_pins=[
        board.GP12,
        board.GP13,
        board.GP14,
        board.GP15,
        board.GP16,
        board.GP17,
        board.GP18,
        board.GP19,
    ],  
    clock=board.GP11, 
    vsync=board.GP7,  
    href=board.GP21,  
    mclk=board.GP20,  
    shutdown=None,
    reset=board.GP10,
)  

cam.colorspace = adafruit_ov2640.OV2640_COLOR_JPEG
cam.size = adafruit_ov2640.OV2640_SIZE_QQVGA
buf = bytearray(cam.capture_buffer_size)

jpeg = cam.capture(buf)
print(f"Captured {len(jpeg)} bytes of jpeg data")
try:
    with open("/sd/jpeg.jpg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(jpeg)
except OSError as e:
    print(e)
    print(
        "A 'read-only filesystem' error occurs if you did not correctly install"
        "\nov2640_jpeg_kaluga1_3_boot.py as CIRCUITPY/boot.py and reset the board"
    )
print("Wrote to CIRCUITPY/jpeg.jpg")
```